# Word VSTO - Insert shape at cursor point?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, position, vsto, shapes

I use the following code to insert a shape (rectangle) to the Word document,

```
Dim oShpWidth As Single
Dim oShpHght As Single
Dim oShpTop As Single
Dim oShpLeft As Single
With Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
    oShpWidth = 225.1
        oShpHght = 224.5
        oShpTop = 0
        oShpLeft = 0
        .Shapes.AddShape(1, 0, 0, oShpWidth, oShpHght).Select()

        With Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.ShapeRange
            .Rotation = 0.0#
                .RelativeHorizontalPosition = Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionCharacter
                .RelativeVerticalPosition = Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionLine
                .Left = oShpTop
                .Top = oShpLeft
        End With
End With
```

But this adds the shape to the top of the current page. I want to add the shape at cursor point. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the shape at the `Selection` Try this:

```
using System;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Drawing;


namespace Sk.WordAddIn
{
    internal class ImageTest
    {

        internal void InsertShapeAtSelection()
        {
            Word.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Word.Document doc = app.ActiveDocument;

            Word.InlineShape shape = app.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg", false, true, Type.Missing);
            shape.Fill.BackColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Transparent);
            shape.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
            shape.Fill.Transparency = 0f;
            shape.Line.Transparency = 0f;
            shape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;

        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Try this:

```
    internal void InsertShapeAtSelection()
    {
        Word.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        Word.Document doc = app.ActiveDocument;
        float left = (float)Convert.ToDouble(app.Selection.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage]);
        float top = (float)Convert.ToDouble(app.Selection.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage]);
        Word.Shape shape = doc.Shapes.AddShape(1, left, top, 225.1f, 224.5f);


        //To change borders and fill use the properties below
        //shape.Fill.BackColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Transparent);
        //shape.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
        //shape.Fill.Transparency = 0f;
        //shape.Line.Transparency = 0f;
        //shape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;

        //To add a picture uncomment the following
        //Word.Range range1 = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
        //range1.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg", false, true, Type.Missing);
    }
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks [Charlie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4923873/charlie). But this code `Word.InlineShape shape = app.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg", false, true, Type.Missing);` works only for adding picture object. It does not work on shape like rectangle. Do you know how to modify this to add shape at cursor point?

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly.

Comment: [Charlie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4923873/charlie), also check this question please: [Word VSTO - Filling a shape does not work in Word 2010 and Word 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589137/word-vsto-filling-a-shape-does-not-work-in-word-2010-and-word-2013). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey [Charlie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4923873/charlie), I have another similar question. Check it out please: [Word VSTO - Change the absolute positions' type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682246/word-vsto-change-the-absolute-positions-type)