# Word VSTO - Filling a shape does not work in Word 2010 and Word 2013?

Tags: vb.net, vsto, shapes, word-2010, word-2013

I use the following VB.NET (VSTO) code to add a shape in MS-Word,

```
Dim app As Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document = app.ActiveDocument
Dim left As Single = CSng(Convert.ToDouble(app.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)))
Dim top As Single = CSng(Convert.ToDouble(app.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)))
Dim shape As Word.Shape = doc.Shapes.AddShape(1, left, top, 225.1F, 224.5F)

shape.Fill.BackColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Transparent)
shape.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
shape.Fill.Transparency = 0.0F
shape.Line.Transparency = 0.0F
shape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
shape.Fill.UserPicture("C:\Newfolder\App1.jpg")
```

What this code does is, it adds a rectangle shape at cursor point, makes it transparent (both background and line) and adds (fills) an image.

This works fine in **Word 2007**. But on **Word 2010** and **Word 2013** there is an issue. It adds the rectangle shape at cursor point and makes it transparent. But it does not fill the image.

```
shape.Fill.UserPicture("C:\Newfolder\App1.jpg")
```

The above line of code does not work in Word 2010 and Word 2013. Other parts works fine. How to modify the code to fill the image in the rectangle shape in Word 2010 and 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `shape.Fill.UserPicture("C:\Newfolder\App1.jpg")` try

```
    Word.Range range = shape1.TextFrame.TextRange;
    range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Newfolder\App1.jpg", false, true, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Hey [Charlie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4923873/charlie), I have another similar question. Check it out please: [Word VSTO - Change the absolute positions' type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682246/word-vsto-change-the-absolute-positions-type)

Comment: Hello [Charlie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4923873/charlie), Do you know the solution to this please: [Word VSTO - Change the absolute positions' type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682246/word-vsto-change-the-absolute-positions-type)

Comment: Hey [Charlie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4923873/charlie), can you check this question please: [Excel VSTO - Get page details?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968511/excel-vsto-get-page-details)