# Word VSTO - Change the absolute positions' type?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, position, vsto, shapes

I use the following VB.NET (VSTO) code to add a shape in MS-Word,

```
Dim app As Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document = app.ActiveDocument
Dim left As Single = CSng(Convert.ToDouble(app.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)))
Dim top As Single = CSng(Convert.ToDouble(app.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)))
Dim shape As Word.Shape = doc.Shapes.AddShape(1, left, top, 225.1F, 224.5F)

shape.Fill.BackColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Transparent)
shape.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
shape.Fill.Transparency = 0.0F
shape.Line.Transparency = 0.0F
shape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
```

What this code does is, it adds a rectangle shape at cursor point and makes it transparent (both background and line).

Now I like to change the absolute positions' type. To explain further, when you select the rectangle shape, then if you select the Ribbon tab **Format > Position > More Layout Options...** as shown in the image below,

[image]

It will open the following dialog,

[image]

In the above dialog I like to change **Column** and **Paragraph** marked by the red rectangles into the type **Margin**. How to do this by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was solved in the link below,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e69584d7-24fe-4396-9a82-26b7dae02584/word-vsto-change-the-absolute-positions-type?forum=vsto

Answer (score 1):

Word provides a Macro recorder. You may use it to get the code generated for you in the background. Thus, you will find what properties and methods exactly should be used to get the job done. See [Record or run a macro](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Record-or-run-a-macro-cd56fb86-d8b2-475c-ba39-9728389feeeb) for more information.

Comment: I tried this method. But when I start recording the macro it does not select the shape object.

Comment: Also the **Position** button is disabled when recording the macro.